XSLT: Want to use a Variable to Exclude from Sum of Node-set
I have xml that has multiple buckets that are being summed together in a Total
I am using xslt 2.0.....
       <RPTTIME>
            <ATTRTYPE>sickPaid</ATTRTYPE>
            <VALUE>9</VALUE>
        </RPTTIME>
        <RPTTIME>
            <ATTRTYPE>annLeave</ATTRTYPE>
            <VALUE>9</VALUE>
        </RPTTIME>
        <RPTTIME>
            <ATTRTYPE>sickPaid</ATTRTYPE>
            <VALUE>9</VALUE>
        </RPTTIME>
        <RPTTIME>
            <ATTRTYPE>regHour</ATTRTYPE>
            <VALUE>8</VALUE>
        </RPTTIME>

Current code
<xsl:value-of select="sum(./RPTTIME/VALUE)"/>

Results: 35 being reported
I have been asked to exclude some of the values based on the type (annLeave, sickPaid, etc).  Desired output in example data would be 8.
This code works
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(./RPTTIME[not(ATTRTYPE=('noMap','otherLeave','leaveWOPay','annLeave','sickPaid','sickNotPaid'))]/VALUE)"/>

I would prefer to use a variable instead.  Here is what I am trying but it is being ignored
<xsl:variable name='excludeList'>
  <ATTRTYPE>otherLeave</ATTRTYPE>
  <ATTRTYPE>leaveWOPay</ATTRTYPE>
  <ATTRTYPE>annLeave</ATTRTYPE>
  <ATTRTYPE>sickPaid</ATTRTYPE>
  <ATTRTYPE>sickNotPaid</ATTRTYPE>
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:value-of select="sum(./RPTTIME[ATTRTYPE != $excludeList]/VALUE)"/>

Result: 35
I have also tried
<xsl:value-of select="sum(./RPTTIME[not(ATTRTYPE = $excludeList)]/VALUE)"/>

Result: 35

I would suggest to just use a string sequence e.g. <xsl:variable name='excludeList' select="'noMap','otherLeave','leaveWOPay','annLeave','sickPaid','sickNotPaid'"/> and then use the previous code but of course with the variable i.e.  <xsl:value-of select="sum(./RPTTIME[not(ATTRTYPE=$excludeList)]/VALUE)"/>
If you want to use your element sequence variable use
<xsl:variable name='excludeList' as="element()*">
  <ATTRTYPE>otherLeave</ATTRTYPE>
  <ATTRTYPE>leaveWOPay</ATTRTYPE>
  <ATTRTYPE>annLeave</ATTRTYPE>
  <ATTRTYPE>sickPaid</ATTRTYPE>
  <ATTRTYPE>sickNotPaid</ATTRTYPE>
</xsl:variable>

and of course the variable in place of your previous sequence
<xsl:value-of select="sum(./RPTTIME[not(ATTRTYPE=$excludeList)]/VALUE)"/>


Using the String Sequence worked perfect...Thanks

Given a well-formed XML input:
<ROOT>
  <RPTTIME>
    <ATTRTYPE>sickPaid</ATTRTYPE>
    <VALUE>9</VALUE>
  </RPTTIME>
  <RPTTIME>
    <ATTRTYPE>annLeave</ATTRTYPE>
    <VALUE>9</VALUE>
  </RPTTIME>
  <RPTTIME>
    <ATTRTYPE>sickPaid</ATTRTYPE>
    <VALUE>9</VALUE>
  </RPTTIME>
  <RPTTIME>
    <ATTRTYPE>regHour</ATTRTYPE>
    <VALUE>8</VALUE>
  </RPTTIME>
</ROOT>

you can do:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name='excludeList'>
    <ATTRTYPE>otherLeave</ATTRTYPE>
    <ATTRTYPE>leaveWOPay</ATTRTYPE>
    <ATTRTYPE>annLeave</ATTRTYPE>
    <ATTRTYPE>sickPaid</ATTRTYPE>
    <ATTRTYPE>sickNotPaid</ATTRTYPE>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <result>
         <xsl:value-of select="sum(RPTTIME[not(ATTRTYPE = $excludeList/ATTRTYPE)]/VALUE)"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

to get this result:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>8</result>

Pay attention to the syntax: the predicate [not(value = $sequence)] is very different from your attempt of [value != $sequence]. See the rules of comparison here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-comparisons
